Version code of android fetch in ionic capacitor application
async getAppInfo() { const info =  App.getInfo(); alert('App version:'+ (await info).version); }
this was not given version rather it displaying error
ERROR Error: Not implemented on web.
at AppWeb.unimplemented
Can some one help me on this your text
I need to fetch the version code in capacitor
I was trying to get the version code because I need to force to user to update the application
